# Original Nikud for Raphael?

Tags: hebrew, names, malach-angel, vowels-nekudot

רָפָאֵל or רְפָאֵל

What is the original nikud? I have seen some variation before and wonder if the name should begin with Kamatz or Sheva?

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Chronicles 1:26:7

Comment: Why not make that an official answer?

Comment: @N.T. it's not the angel

Comment: I've only see Rafael in non Jewish sources

Comment: @DoubleAA The question doesn't say "angel".

Comment: @msh true but the tag does

Answer (score -1):

The Reish is with a Shva "רְפָא" - Language of request. (There is no differentiation between the name of the angel and of a boy.)
~Rav Eldad Cohen

Comment: Are you Rav Eldad Cohen? Or is he well known enough that I should recognize his name? I'm confused what your source is.

Comment: He answers Halachic Shailos on a few different platforms. I believe he is Sefaradi but there would be no difference.